# Migration in Laravel Lumen 5.4 throws 'non-numeric value encountered' error

Tags: laravel-5, lumen, illuminate-container

I am running against this error when running my migration:

```
In DatabaseMigrationRepository.php line 113:

A non-numeric value encountered
```

The error is thrown on line 113 here https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.4/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php

Comment: Are you on PHP 7? This sounds like more to batch number is missing in DB and +1 to it causing E_NOTICE.

Comment: yes. running php 7.